# C server and a java client. How to read the full string?

Tags: java, c++, c, sockets, winsock

I've implemented a C server and a Java client which communicate to each other through TCP. The problem is when the client sends a string, the recv() call in C server just reads a character and returns immediately. If I put a breakpoint at recv() and then do a step-over, the server receives the whole string that was sent.
Here's the recv call I'm using in C

```
char tempBuffer[256] = {'\0'};  
int retVal = recv(hClientSocket, tempBuffer, sizeof(tempBuffer), 0);
```

And here's the Java client.

```
clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 24886);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
outToServer.writeBytes("alert(\"hi\")");
```

My question is, is there a way in which I can make this work without having to put a while loop in my C server code to receive each character separately? What's the best way to do this?
I implemented the C++ client given [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_client.cpp) and it works fine. So I'm guessing it's some problem in Java+C++ interoperability. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys! I decided to use a delimiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although what Scott M says is true on a Java side ( about using `flush` ), you will have to rework your whole communication protocol.

You will have to either tell to C-code, how many bytes are expected to be sent (this will be the easiest to track), or use some sort of termination character, to recognize that the string input is over ( e.g. null terminator byte ).

There is absolutely no guarantee that the network layer will not chop the transition arbitrarily, so code defensively and expect `recv` always to recieve a partial data, which you will have to assemble for your internal consumption.

Answer (score 2):

Try flushing the java stream. They are normally buffered, which will cause some delay in the writing of bytes to a stream. Long enough to mess up code at full speed, short enough to send the whole string while debugging.

Comment: If we are sending repeatedly .. there is no guarantee each recv t server fill give a single complete string.. It may contain parts of other writeBytes...

Comment: thats a great point. Looking at the other answers I definitely missed that, but I still think flushing after a write to unmanaged recv calls is a good idea. Check Alexander Pogrebnyak's and Nikolai N Fetissov's answers for a better explanation thatn I could give.

Answer (score 2):

With TCP there's no way around "putting a while loop around `recv()`". TCP is a stream protocol built on top of limited-size packet service (IP). TCP does its own "packetization", and is actually very smart about it. This implies that you never know how many bytes the next read from the socket will return.

The well-known strategy that works is to design your application-level protocol so the message itself tells how big it is, then read in a loop until you have full message to process.

Having said that, there's a kludge, namely `MSG_WAITALL` flag for the [`recv(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) call, that you can use to wait for given amount of data, assuming you know how much to expect.

Answer (score 1):

I once tried by having a header indicating length of string .. In that way din have to check for the end of message..